# Solving $(x-y)^2=x+y$

Tags: number-theory

> Find all natural pairs $(x,y)$ such that $(x-y)^2=x+y$.

**Attempt:**

First, factor out the greatest common factor of and $x$ and $y$. Call it $d$, and write $x = ad$ and $y = bd$, so that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. Simplifying the given equation gives $$d(a-b)^2 = a+b.$$Now suppose a prime $p$ divides $a-b$. Then $p$ can't divide $a$ (otherwise it would divide $b$ also, but $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime).

If $p$ is odd, then $a+b \equiv 2a \pmod{p}$, a contradiction since $2a$ can't be divisible by $p$.

If $p$ is even, then $4$ must divide $(a-b)^2$ and so $a+b$ as well. This must mean that $a$ and $b$ must both be odd (they can't both be even) and so we have two cases.

If $a+b \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$, then we have: Thus $a-b$ is not divisible by any prime and so $a = b+1$ or $b = a+1$. In the first case, $d = 2b+1$ and in the second case, $d = 2a+1$. Thus, the general solution is $x = (b+1)(2b+1)$ and  $y = b(2b+1)$ and its permutations.

How do I deal with the case that $a+b \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n=x-y$, then $n^2=n+2y\iff y=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and $n^2=2x-n\iff x=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. You can check that indeed whenever $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $x=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $y=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ gives a solution, so we have actually found all of them.

Comment: So you don't need to do it like I did?

Comment: Maybe one could complete your attempt to a solution, but I think its perhaps a bit more straightforward to do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x-y)^2=x+y \Rightarrow x^2-x(1+2y)+y^2-y=0$$

$$x=\frac{1+2y\pm \sqrt{1+8y}}{2} \quad (1)$$

Once $x \in \Bbb Z$ then

$$1+8y=k^2 \Rightarrow y=\frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{8} \quad (2)$$

and backing to $(1)$ we get:

$$x=\frac{(k+3)(k+1)}{8} \quad \text{or} \quad x=\frac{(k-3)(k-1)}{8} \quad (3)$$

and in order to get $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ we must have:

$$k\equiv \{1,3,5,7\} (\mod 8) \quad (4)$$

So we have infinite solutions given by $(2)$ and $(3)$ such that $k$ fits the condition $(4)$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is necessary to draw a formula for the solution in the general form:

In the equation: $$(x-y)^2=x+y$$

Solutions can be written:

$$x=\frac{a(a+1)}{2}+\frac{b(b-1)}{2}-ab$$

$$y=\frac{a(a-1)}{2}+\frac{b(b+1)}{2}-ab$$

$a,b$ - what some integers.